# Installing LyX on ubuntu 14.04 offline?

Tags: 14.04, apt, texlive, lyx

Since my school's firewall have blocked downloads exceed 150 MB, I can't install lyX using terminal. It's giving me a 404 and 403 errors. 
But I can download anything from my home machine literally. So can you help me what to download in order to install LyX(including TexLive) and how to install using that download files.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think so....

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
sudo apt-get install <packages you want> --print-uris -qq
```

And it will give you the list of files you need. Download all of them, put them in `/var/cache/apt/archive/` in your Ubuntu laptop. Then say `sudo apt-get install <packages you want>` and they will all install. Hopefully.

There are more elegant ways of doing this, this is just a hack.